# Robots.txt for a wordpress site - what if we have another server hosting pages on the same domain that we want to hide from indexing?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

We have a wordpress site on a domain, let's call it domain.com. We have our old product hosted on app.domain.com but it's hosted on a separate server from the wordpress site. Right now, both domain.com and app.domain.com are indexed in search results. We want to block app.domain.com from indexing and instead ensure search engines crawl our new product, hosted on rpa.domain.com - Can we do all of this from the robots.txt we have set up at domain.com/robots.txt? If so, how do we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Search engines consider domain.com and app.domain.com as separate sites. You'd need to give app.domain.com its own robots.txt.